# bxslider is hidden, but on window resize appears

Tags: ajax, windows, resize, bxslider

I have bxslider on my php file that is loaded with ajax. and when i open page slider is hidden, nothing is shown, but when i resize window or click on inspect element slider appears and works correctly.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to guess why your code doesn't work without seeing the code? Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that the moment the function is called it does not find the element or even if it doesn find it, its not able to calculate height properly because the element might be getting loaded AFTER the `bxSlider` call or maybe hidden or something like that. But when you resize the window (or inspect element, they both fire `window.resize`) `bxSlider` is coded to respond to that and readjust its height and width, thus displaying your slider.

I hope it helps you.